# How do I exit a for or a while loop with user input in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("-------Welcome to the Radius calculator-------");

        String input = new String (" ");
        while(input.equals("END")==false) {

            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                for (int e = 5; e > 0; e--)
                {
                    {
                        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
                        System.out.println("Hey you can use this calcultor " + e + " more time(s) till yoh have to purchase our full version only 3.99");
                    }
                    System.out.println("Please enter your Radius if not just type in END at any stage during the program");
                    Double num =sc.nextDouble();

                    System.out.println("Enter 1 if you would like to get the area");
                    System.out.println("Enter 2 if you would like to get the circumfrence");

                    int num1 = sc.nextInt();

                    if (num1 == 1) {
                        System.out.println("The area of the circle with the radius " + num + " is :" + (Math.PI) * (num * num));
                    } else if (num1 == 2) {
                        System.out.println("The circumfrence of the circle with the radius " + num + " is :" + (2) * (Math.PI) * (num));

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No answer for you boss");
                        System.out.println("Try again!");
                    }
                    System.out.println("You have used this calculator effiently " + i + " time(s)");
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------");


                }
        }

    }
}
```

Heres my code it works but when i type in END an ERROR comes up.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZxEW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZxEW.png)

If theres any othere tips to make my code for effecient would be much appriciated too.

Comment: `sc.nextDouble()` won't work if the user types "END". Try `sc.nextLine()`, then check if it is "END" and if not try to parse the line as a double.

Comment: you could also replace your while condition to ```(!input.equals("END"))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to ask for the end input during the loops. 
The best way to ask for an input of different types is to use BufferedReader Class

```
BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(System.in));
String input = null;
try {
    input = reader.readLine();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
if (input.equals("END")) {
    break;
}
```

After that you can use :
Integer.parseInt(input);
to cast from String to Integer
And don't forget to clean and simplify your code.